# Difference between "T-Mobile G1" and "HTC Dream"?

Tags: htc-dream

Are there any differences between "T-Mobile G1" and "HTC Dream" besides the name?

If Yes, what are the differences?

Comment: Well there is also the developer version of the phone too.  If you get the T-Mobile version, you are locked in to T-Mobile as a carrier.

Comment: Note that phones often have a different name between the US and Europe, if only for carrier branding reasons

Comment: @Bryan: I got the T-Mobile version in Germany and had absolutely no problems using it with another carrier.

Comment: In the US, at least, you have to get the Unlock SIM code for the phone to be used on a different carrier. http://support.t-mobile.com/doc/tm51885.xml

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not that I have found. It's just different names for the same phone. (A pretty standard marketing practice.)

Some more info here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTC_Dream

Comment: Yep, same phone. 'Dream' is what HTC called the handset, 'T-mobile G1' is how T-mobile sold it.